# Splitting a String into a List(Of T)

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, list, split

I have a data string that I want to split into a list of a class parses out all the data into different properties in the constructor. Each block starts with an STX character and ends with a string "PLC"(I don't know why the vendor didn't use ETX)

so basicly something that takes String datastream splits it at the string "PLC"(and keeps it) and puts it into dataList(of DataClass)

The data stream looks like this:

```
STX1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;+3272;-2145;+3273;-2145;PLC\r\nSTX1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;+3276;-2145;+3272;-2145;PLC\r\nSTX1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;+3281;-2145;+3272;-2145;PLC\r\n
```

and would result in three entries in a list(of dataclass):

```
STX1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;+3272;-2145;+3273;-2145;PLC
STX1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;+3276;-2145;+3272;-2145;PLC
STX1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;+3281;-2145;+3272;-2145;PLC
```

I have looked and I found lots of info on splitting strings in general but nothing about putting it into a class or list. I'm sure I could just do something like:

```
dim datalist as list(of dataclass)
dim splitdata() as string = datastream.split("PLC")
for each data as string in splitdata
    datalist.Add(new dataclass(data))
next
```

but I'm sure there's a more efficant way(probably using regex or LINQ but I'm not really familary with either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help if you have and example input string and output of objects you want.

Comment: I have added the information you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a regular expression would do nicely for splitting the data into the pieces you show:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim s = "STX;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;+3272;-2145;+3273;-2145;PLC\r\nSTX;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;+3276;-2145;+3272;-2145;PLC\r\nSTX;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;+3281;-2145;+3272;-2145;PLC"
        Dim re As New Regex("(STX;.*?;PLC)")

        Dim matches = re.Matches(s)

        If matches.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To matches.Count - 1
                Console.WriteLine(matches(i).Value)
                'TODO: do whatever is required with matches(i)
            Next
        End If

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

```
STX;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;+3272;-2145;+3273;-2145;PLC
STX;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;+3276;-2145;+3272;-2145;PLC
STX;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;+3281;-2145;+3272;-2145;PLC
```

In the above regex, the parentheses capture a group, the text parts `STX;` and `;PLC` are literals to match, and the `.*?` matches anything (`.`) zero-or-more times (`*`) until the following text. The `?` makes it "non-greedy". If it was greedy, it would match everything up until the final `;PLC` and you would end up with the match being the whole line.

**Edit**

In the light of your comments, I suggest using the [String.Split Method (String(), StringSplitOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim s As String = "STX;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;+3272;-2145;+3273;-2145;PLC\r\nSTX;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;+3276;-2145;+3272;-2145;PLC\r\nSTX;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;+3281;-2145;+3272;-2145;PLC"
        ' transform the test string to its actual form
        s = s.Replace("\r\n", vbCrLf)

        ' split it into the required parts as an array
        Dim parts() As String = s.Split({vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        ' show the split worked as desired
        For i = 0 To parts.Length - 1
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Part {0}: {1}", i, parts(i)))
            'TODO: do something with parts(i)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

You didn't mention which version of VS you are using, so if the above complains about the line

```
Dim parts() As String = s.Split({vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

then please replace it with

```
Dim splitAt() As String = {VbCrLf}
Dim parts() As String = s.Split(splitAt, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

**Also**, if the data is being read from a file then you can use the [File.ReadAllLines Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to grab all the lines into an array in one go.

Comment: This works! However I realized additionally between the different blocks of text there are \r\n. So I can actually do a string.split on that. So out of curiosity do you know which method would be more efficient as there will be 6-8 threads doing this all at once? My guess is string.split() does something similar automagically in the background. Howerer if it doesn't make a difference I'll use your method just to be fancy!(Note I would upvote you but I don't have enough reputation points if I get them I'll come back and do so)

Comment: @BinaryDuck When you write "\r\n", I take it you mean the four separate chars `\ r \ n`. I suspect String.Split would be faster, but you can't always tell until you test it on real data.

Comment: I actually meant the ascii character representations of those so just the two.

Comment: @BinaryDuck Ahh... then there are more options available. Please see the edit to my earlier answer.

Comment: Andrew thank you again for your throughness. I am using VS2010 so the first option works and I can split on the VbCrLf. Additionally the data is coming from a datastream over the network.